# map git remote submodule directory in jenkin

Tags: maven, jenkins, github

I have a git repository consisting of two sub-modules. I need to clone the only submodule as my pom.xml required by Jenkins is present in the submodule. How to specify the path of the submodule in Jenkins.

Comment: So you have `root/pom.xml` and `root/mod1/pom.xml` and `root/mod2/pom.xml` and `root` will be replaced with your git repo root? Then you build the `root/pom.xml` via jenkins via `mvn deploy` ? I don't understand your problem?

Comment: My pom.xml resides in one sub-module of my remote git repository and not in root. for Eg. repository_name/Submodule1/pom.xml.  I want to clone only files in  repository_name/Submodule1/{files}

Comment: So that's the issue. Restructure your repository and it makes building/configuring etc. easier...

Comment: "_consisting of two sub-modules_" and "_the only submodule_" is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Git submodule repos are full-featured repos which can be treated as if they were completely independent/standalone. (The only connections are links in the main repo to refs of the submodules.) So, you can enter your submodule repo's URL in:

Project config → ***Source Code Management*** → *Git* → *Repositories* → *Repository URL*.